# If $A$ is nonnegative definite then so is $BAB'$

Tags: matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ be an $m$x$m$ nonnegative definite matrix, while $B$ is an $n$x$m$ matrix. Show that $BAB'$ is a nonnegative definite matrix.

I know by definition that a nonnegative definite matrix has the following definition: $x'Ax \ge 0$. However, I do not know how to employ this definition to arrive to the answer.

Comment: $$x'(BAB')x=(B'x)'A(B'x)\geqslant0$$

Comment: How does it follow that $(B')x'A(B'x) \ge 0$?

Comment: @CarlYocto: That is because $A$ is non-negative definite. (If it helps, write $y = B'x$.)

Comment: Carl: The thing in your comment does not exist. The thing in mine is nonnegative because $y'Ay\geqslant0$ for every $y$ and one can choose $y=B'x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Clive and Did. From your comments, the solution is pretty straightforward.